# Linear Mixed Model: Multiple data points per participant at multiple time points

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, linear-model

I am looking to compare change between pre and post time points separated by fatigue.
The data has multiple participants and each participant has 6 data points pre fatigue and 6 data points post fatigue. All data at a single time point were collected in <60 seconds so are expected to be similar.

Is it necessary to average the 6 values for each subject taken at a given time point and only input one value per time point into the model, or can linear mixed model cope with the structure of multiple results at a single time point?

Example code/data is below

````
x <- data.frame(subject=rep(1:5,each=12),
                time = rep(c("Pre", "Post"), each = 6), result = c(
                  -2.28, -6.97, -6.08, -6.07, 8.04, -7.28, -1.75, -3.19,
                  1.58, -1.28, -3.32, -2.87, 3.01, 0.25, -1.02, 1.4,
                  5.55, 3.68, 2.08, 2.35, 2.76, 3.27, 3.95, 2.81,
                  -3.22, -4.5, -3.6, -4.49, 3.44, 2.21, -5.38, -3.99,
                  -5.52, -3.97, -4.7, -9.58, -10.25, -9.93, -9.61, -10.83,
                  -10.62, -8.19, -9.11, -9.51, -9.24, -9.34, -9.07, 10.75,
                  10.07, 10.02, 11.44, 11.72, 12.09, 11.19, 12.05, -5.15,
                  12.55, 14.02, 13.96, 13.39
                ))

x$subject <- as.factor(x$subject)
x$time <- as.factor(x$time)

xModel <-  lmer(result ~ time +
                             (1|subject), x)```
````